# Translating gdal.polygonize from qgis 2 to 3

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdal, polygonize

I was using this simple code to polygonize rasters using qgis 2.18:

```
general.runalg('gdalogr:polygonize', inRaster, 'DN', outShape)
```

I've tried converting it to use in qgis 3.2 like so:

```
general.run('gdal:polygonize', inRaster, 'DN', outShape)
```

But this error pops up and I can't seem to figure it out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.2\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 96, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 132, in runAlgorithm
    feedback.reportError(msg)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reportError'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should be using `processing.runalg` as indicated by the QGIS API [docs](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html) for your QGIS version of choice. You check the input parameters by running `processing.algorithmHelp('gdal:polygonize')`, it provides several parameters which need to be entered in dict format after you refer to the algorithm you want. These are INPUT, BAND, FIELD, EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS and OUTPUT.

Therefore your command could look like this:

```
processing.run("gdal:polygonize", {'INPUT':'D:/TEMP/Stackexchange/raster.asc','BAND':1,'FIELD':'DN','EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS':False,'OUTPUT':'D:/TEMP/Stackexchange/out.shp'})
```

Alternately you could also run it using the regular qgis processing toolbox and then check the command history, which will provide a "pythonized" call to the function (similar to ArcGIS geoprocessing history):

[image]